# can't use passed instance of socket.io to class as event listener

Tags: node.js, typescript, socket.io

I'm creating nodejs app for matches:
when i pass the socket instance to the match class the connection dies if one of the clients disconnected and socket listener in the match class never works again

server.ts

```
class SocketServer {
    public server: Server;
    public matches: Match[] = [];
    private io: socketIo.Server;

    constructor() {
        this.createServer();
        this.sockets();
        this.listen();
    }

    private createServer(): void {
        this.server = createServer();
    }

    private  sockets(): void {
        this.io = socketIo(this.server);
    }

    private listen(): void {
        this.server.listen(this.port, this.host, () => {
            console.log("http://%s:%s", this.host, this.port);
        });

        const nsp = this.io.of("my-namespace")
            .on("connection", (socket: any) => {
            const query = {
                client_id: Number(socket.handshake.query.client_id),
                match: Number(socket.handshake.query.match) };
            socket.join(query.match.toString());
            socket.on("subscribe", (room: string) => {
                socket.join(room);
            });
            socket.on("unsubscribe", (room: string) => {
                socket.leave(room);
            });
            if (this.matches.length > 0) {
                const match = this.findMatchById(query.match);
                if (match === undefined) {
                    this.matches.push(new Match(nsp, socket, query));
                }
            } else {
                this.matches.push(new Match(nsp, socket, query));
            }
        });
    }

 }
```

in the match class when i use `io.emit()` it works fine but `socket.on()` it does not work after any client disconnected from the match

match.ts

```
export default class Match {
    constructor(namespace: any, socket: any, query: any) {
        this.namespace = namespace;
        this.room = query.match.toString();
        this.id = query.match;
        this.main(socket, query);
    }
    public async main(socket: any, query: any) {
        if (this.initiated === false) {
            await this.initMatch();
        }


        socket.on("player-ready", (data: any) => {
            // some code
        });
        socket.on("disconnect", () => {
            // some code
        });
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where the problem was, when i am passing the socket instance to the Match constructor, i let one client connected to the room, and because of the condition

```
if (this.matches.length > 0) {
    const match = this.findMatchById(query.match);
    if (match === undefined) {
        this.matches.push(new Match(nsp, socket, query));
    }
} else {
    this.matches.push(new Match(nsp, socket, query));
}
```

i never let anyone else to be registered in the same match so i created some public methods in the match class and used it in the server file like this:

match.ts

```
public makeClientReady(id: number): void {
    // some code
}
```

server.ts

```
const nsp = this.io.of("my-namespace")
        .on("connection", (socket: any) => {
        const query = {
            client_id: Number(socket.handshake.query.client_id),
            match: Number(socket.handshake.query.match) };
        socket.join(query.match.toString());
        socket.on("subscribe", (room: string) => {
            socket.join(room);
        });
        socket.on("unsubscribe", (room: string) => {
            socket.leave(room);
        });
        if (this.matches.length > 0) {
            const match = this.findMatchById(query.match);
            if (match === undefined) {
                this.matches.push(new Match(nsp, socket, query));
            }
        } else {
            this.matches.push(new Match(nsp, socket, query));
        }

        socket.on("player-ready", (data: any) => {
            match.makeClientReady(Number(data.id));
        });
    });
```